# How do I reorder or rearrange the output below

Tags: text-processing, columns

Here in my **INPUT**:

```
0015:"IDPTS3O"  
0091:"ODMBS1I"  
0015:"IDPTS3O"  
0091:"ODMBS1I"  
0015:"IDPTS3O"  
0091:"ODMBS1I"  
0015:"IDPTS3O"  
0034:"ADTSS1I"  
0015:"IDPTS3O"  
0034:"ADTSS1I"  
0015:"IDPTS3O"  
0034:"ADTSS1I"  
0015:"IDPTS3O"  
0036:"ADTSS2I"  
0015:"IDPTS3O"  
0036:"ADTSS2I"  
0015:"IDPTS3O"  
0036:"ADTSS2I"  
0015:"IDPTS3O"  
0034:"ADTSS1I"  
0015:"IDPTS3O"  
0034:"ADTSS1I"  
0015:"IDPTS3O"  
0034:"ADTSS1I"  
0015:"IDPTS3O"  
0036:"ADTSS2I"  
0015:"IDPTS3O"  
0036:"ADTSS2I"  
0015:"IDPTS3O"  
0036:"ADTSS2I"
```

I would like the **OUTPUT** to display as follows: The "**O**" ending together and the "**I**" endings together on the same column

```
0015:"IDPTS3O"  0091:"ODMBS1I"
0015:"IDPTS3O"  0091:"ODMBS1I"
0015:"IDPTS3O"  0091:"ODMBS1I"
0015:"IDPTS3O"  0034:"ADTSS1I"
.
.
.
```

Comment: Could you describe in words what you want to do?

Answer (score 4):

The command [`paste`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/paste.1.html) combines lines from **multiple input files** into one file with multiple columns, one from each file.

It can be used to combine lines of **the same** file into a file with multiple columns, such that consecutive lines end up in consecutive columns in the output.

The idea is to use one input multiple times for each row, instead of multiple inputs.
That's best done reading from standard input, and using `-`, which represents standard input as an input file, multiple times:

```
<filename paste -d ' ' - -
```

- `<filename` reads `filename` to standard input
- `-d ' '` sets the separator between columns to a space, instead of the default, a tab.
- `- -` represents two times standard input as input file one and two, so for each line, standard input is read two times, creating the first and second column.

Answer (score 3):

While the canonical way to solve this problem involves `paste`, here I offer an `awk` alternative wherein the output record separator is set to a space on odd and newline on even lines

```
awk '{ORS=NR%2?" ":"\n";print}' file
```

Comment: This Alternative is not working. See error below:              > awk '{ORS=NR%1?" ":"\n";print}' eosArrged.txt
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1

Comment: @chydo, what version of awk are you running?

Answer (score 2):

Feel free to try:

```
paste -d " " - - < filename
```

Comment: I guess it must be "$ paste -d " " - - < filename"

Comment: The printf option is not working, see error:                       > printf "%s  %s\n" $( < eosArrged.txt )
Illegal variable name.